# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at method of concurrency approaches comprise

Tags: java, concurrency, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to run some comparison of different approaches for concurrency technique.

But it throws next exceptions:

```
Warmup
BaseLine     :      21246915
============================
Cycles       :         50000
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-5" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100000
    at concurrency.BaseLine.accumulate(SynchronizationComparisons.java:89)
    at concurrency.Accumulator$Modifier.run(SynchronizationComparisons.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100000
    at concurrency.BaseLine.accumulate(SynchronizationComparisons.java:89)
    at concurrency.Accumulator$Modifier.run(SynchronizationComparisons.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import java.util.*;

import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

abstract class Accumulator {
    public static long cycles = 50000L;
    // Number of Modifiers and Readers during each test:
    private static final int N = 4;
    public static ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N * 2);
    private static CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(N * 2 + 1);
    protected volatile int index = 0;
    protected volatile long value = 0;
    protected long duration = 0;
    protected String id = "error";
    protected final static int SIZE = 100000;
    protected static int[] preLoaded = new int[SIZE];
    static {
        // Load the array of random numbers:
        Random rand = new Random(47);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            preLoaded[i] = rand.nextInt();
    }

    public abstract void accumulate();

    public abstract long read();

    private class Modifier implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            for (long i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
                accumulate();
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class Reader implements Runnable {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private volatile long value;

        public void run() {
            for (long i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
                value = read();
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void timedTest() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            exec.execute(new Modifier());
            exec.execute(new Reader());
        }
        try {
            barrier.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
        printf("%-13s: %13d\n", id, duration);
    }

    public static void report(Accumulator acc1, Accumulator acc2) {
        printf("%-22s: %.2f\n", acc1.id + "/" + acc2.id, (double) acc1.duration / (double) acc2.duration);
    }
}

class BaseLine extends Accumulator {
    {
        id = "BaseLine";
    }

    public void accumulate() {
        value += preLoaded[index++];
        if (index >= SIZE)
            index = 0;
    }

    public long read() {
        return value;
    }
}

class SynchronizedTest extends Accumulator {
    {
        id = "synchronized";
    }

    public synchronized void accumulate() {
        value += preLoaded[index++];
        if (index >= SIZE)
            index = 0;
    }

    public synchronized long read() {
        return value;
    }
}

class LockTest extends Accumulator {
    {
        id = "Lock";
    }
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void accumulate() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            value += preLoaded[index++];
            if (index >= SIZE)
                index = 0;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public long read() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return value;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

class AtomicTest extends Accumulator {
    {
        id = "Atomic";
    }
    private AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private AtomicLong value = new AtomicLong(0);

    public void accumulate() {
        // Oops! Relying on more than one Atomic at
        // a time doesn't work. But it still gives us
        // a performance indicator:
        int i = index.getAndIncrement();
        value.getAndAdd(preLoaded[i]);
        if (++i >= SIZE)
            index.set(0);
    }

    public long read() {
        return value.get();
    }
}

public class SynchronizationComparisons {
    static BaseLine baseLine = new BaseLine();
    static SynchronizedTest synch = new SynchronizedTest();
    static LockTest lock = new LockTest();
    static AtomicTest atomic = new AtomicTest();

    static void test() {
        print("============================");
        printf("%-12s : %13d\n", "Cycles", Accumulator.cycles);
        baseLine.timedTest();
        synch.timedTest();
        lock.timedTest();
        atomic.timedTest();
        Accumulator.report(synch, baseLine);
        Accumulator.report(lock, baseLine);
        Accumulator.report(atomic, baseLine);
        Accumulator.report(synch, lock);
        Accumulator.report(synch, atomic);
        Accumulator.report(lock, atomic);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iterations = 5; // Default
        if (args.length > 0) // Optionally change iterations
            iterations = new Integer(args[0]);
        // The first time fills the thread pool:
        print("Warmup");
        baseLine.timedTest();
        // Now the initial test doesn't include the cost
        // of starting the threads for the first time.
        // Produce multiple data points:
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            test();
            Accumulator.cycles *= 2;
        }
        Accumulator.exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**How to solve this trouble?**

Comment: Looking at the code, the first thing I would do is declare this in BaseLine class `public synchronized void accumulate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `preLoaded` is of size 100000. So, the valid index starts from `0` to `99999` since array index starts from `0`. You need to swap the statements in method `accumulate()`

Change this

```
        value += preLoaded[index++]; //index validity is not done
        if (index >= SIZE)
            index = 0;
```

to

```
        if (index >= SIZE)
            index = 0;
        value += preLoaded[index++]; // index validity is done and controlled
```

This will not make the index go to 100000. It will make it to 0 when it turns 100000 before the index value is accessed.

Note : The above code is vulnerable only in multi-threaded environment. The above code will work fine with single thread.

Comment: If it was single threaded, it would be OK because as soon as `index` reaches `SIZE` it gets reset to 0. But the problem is, multiple threads are incrementing it. But your answer is good that it checks the validity of the index before using it.

Comment: @anonymous It looks like OP has done it in multithreaded code. I have put a note as well that the OP code is fine with single threaded environment.

Comment: @Octopus what about `AtomicTest`? It fails there. You suggestions is really useful.

Comment: @nazar_art It's likely to be the same problem because the method itself isn't threadsafe, make the same change there as you made for `BaseLine`.

Comment: @Octopus I changed to `int i = index.getAndIncrement();
  if (++i >= SIZE)
   index.set(0);
  value.getAndAdd(preLoaded[i]);` It doesn't work.

Comment: @nazar_art You have to check `i` before you use it to access the array index. `int i = index.getAndIncrement();if (i >= SIZE)
            i = 0;
        value.getAndAdd(preLoaded[i]);
        if (++i >= SIZE)
            index.set(0);`

Comment: @Octopus Now it's ok. But output keep throwing `Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-7" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100000
 at concurrency.BaseLine.accumulate(SynchronizationComparisons.java:94)` here is 94 line - `value += preLoaded[index++]; // index validity is done and controlled` from BaseLine.

Comment: Can you make this method `accumulate` as  `synchronized`? You have put `synchronized` for all other methods

Answer (score 2):

Change BaseLine class and AtomicTest class:

```
 class BaseLine extends Accumulator {
  {
    id = "BaseLine";
  }
  public void accumulate() {
    int early = index++;  // early add and assign to a temp.
    if(early >= SIZE) {
      index = 0;
      early = 0;
    }  
    value += preLoaded[early];
  }
  public long read() {
    return value;
  }
}

class AtomicTest extends Accumulator {
  {
    id = "Atomic";
  }
  private AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
  private AtomicLong value = new AtomicLong(0);
  public void accumulate() {
    int early = index.getAndIncrement();
    if(early >= SIZE) {
      index.set(0);
      early = 0;
    }
    value.getAndAdd(preLoaded[early]);
  }
  public long read() {
    return value.get();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're running into concurrent executions of `BaseLine.accumulate()` near the boundary of the `preLoaded` array.

You've got 4 threads hammering away at an unsynchronized method, which is potentially leading to `index` being incremented to `100000` by say, Thread 1, and before Thread 1 can set it back to `0`, one of Thread 2, 3 or 4 is coming in and attempting to access `preLoaded[index++]`, which fails as `index` is still `100000`.